# Trying to Style Super Slim Mailchimp form

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm trying to style the superslim Mailchimp form to go onto our homepage. I've created a new div to wrap it all in, and copied and pasted the code in and currently it appears below:

```
<div class="mailChimp">
    ****Copied Code****
   <form action="blahblahblah" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
   <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address" required>
</div>
<div class="clear">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-   subscribe" class="button">
</div>
```

Then in my CSS:

```
#mailChimp{
    max-width:245px;
    margin-left: 55px
}

#mce-EMAIL{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 95%
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Now, this seems to have the correct IDs attached as it appears correctly in Dreamweaver. However, when I upload the files to the server then none of the CSS styling is applied.

None of the css is applying, which is frustrating! Even the div ID mailChimp isn't. I can't even find it in the inspected element.

Am I selecting the ID's incorrectly?

The main confusion comes from the fact that It appears correctly in Dreamweaver which is reading from the style sheet, but not when I upload both files live.

Answer (score 1):

'mailChimp' is a class, so it starts with a . in the css not a #:

```
.mailChimp{
max-width:245px;
margin-left: 55px;
}
```

The margin-left had not been closed with a ;. Also, in mce-email, you have not closed the width tab with a ;.

In your css, you have '#mc-embedded-subscribe' but in the HTML is it written with a big gap between embedded- and subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The big gap for embedded- seems to be a formatting issue when I pasted it into here - the code has no gap.

Thanks for pointing out the other bits though! I can't believe I missed something so simple.

However, having updated these, the issue persists of showing up in Dreamweaver, but not in browser.